# phone app that directs user to mobile site

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

Im trying to make an app that will basically be able to be downloaded directly from my mobile website. I honestly want to just make something so users can download the app to their phone and when they click on it they will be directed to my mobile website. So basically i just need to design the button and make it so it can be downloaded and installed on mobile phones.

I have searched the net looking for how to do this and nobody specifically explains how to build this. Does anyone have any idea of how i can go about this?

Comment: On iOS: `[[UIApplication sharedApplictation] openURL:mobileWebsiteURL];`

Comment: "download the app to their phone and when they click on it they will be directed to my mobile website" so do you mean that the app is essentially a bookmark? If so, you can add the `apple-touch-icon` and `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` meta tags to your site, and both iOS and Android will handle them. to install on iOS you 'Add to Homescreen' via the arrow icon in safari, in Android you bookmark, then long press the bookmark and there is some similar Homescreen option

Comment: Yes basically a bookmark. I want it so there is an app button on their home screen, if thats where they choose to place it, and they can click it and it pulls up my mobile site.

Comment: I tried this method with my android.. works brilliantly and is what i want, but most people dont want to take 5seconds to figure this out. Id like to have something that works exactly like this but can just be directly downloaded to the phone from my site.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me with Android is email the APK file. The user can open the mail on their phone. In Gmail you will see the install button which of course can be used to install the app.

I use this to distribute my apps outside the market.

Comment: I guess my real question is where would i find the coding to build an app like this?

Comment: You can build the Android app with Eclipse ADT. And email it to you're users manually.